# accessing foreignKey inside the template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

well it's quiet simple.
2 models with ManyToMany relation:

```
class Artist(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
   slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True,
            help_text='Uniq value for artist page URL, created from name')
   birth_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)


class Song(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=255)  
   slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True,
            help_text='Unique value for product page URL, create from name.')
   youtube_link = models.URLField(blank=False)
   artists = models.ManyToManyField(Artist)
```

my view suppose to display latest 5 songs:

```
def songs(request, template_name="artists/songs.html"):
   song_list = Song.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')[:5]
   return render_to_response(template_name, locals(),
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and the problem is in the template... i want to display the artist name
but just dont realy know how to do it, i tried:

```
{% for song in song_list %}
    {{ artists__name }} - {{ song.title }} 
{% endfor %}
```

would appreciate any help !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try changing your template code to:

```
{% for song in song_list %}
  {% for artist in song.artists.all %}
    {{ artist.name }} - {{ song.title }} 
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: @kaycee - I've updated my answer - could you try again? Also, rather than posting additional queries as answers, add them as comments below the answer you're referring to.

Answer (score 1):

`artists` is another type of manager, so you have to iterate through `artists.all` and print the `name` attribute of each element.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I worked on above solution of Mr @Dominic Rodger, but because am using Django version 3.2 it did not worked for me. Therefore, the problem may remain the same but according to how Django version changes, the way to solve them sometimes become different. If you're using Django 3.x use below solution.

In views.py

```
def songs(request):
   song_list = Song.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')[:5]
   song_list = {'song_list':song_list}
   return render(request, 'artists/songs.html', song_list)
```

In your HTML Template use code below

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Artist - Song Title</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for song in song_list %}
            </tr>
                <td>{{ song.artist.name }} - {{ song.title }}</td> 
            <tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
</table>
```

In urls.py

```
path('songs/', views.songs, name='songs'),
```

If you're running source code from localhost, then type on your browser http://127.0.0.1:8000/songs/

Thank you ....